# Azure Integration Runtime Cross Service Utilization

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-purview

I have successfully created a  runtime in DataFactory and have stuff running.

When I go to create another runtime in Azure Purview, it prompts to remove or repair which results in the lose of the ADF one. How can I utilise the same runtime on multiple services.?

I came across this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-shared-self-hosted-integration-runtime-powershell) which details how I can create shared runtime but only within the ADF.

Did I miss something? Given that runtime is [defined](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39717) as `The Microsoft Integration Runtime is a customer managed data integration and scanning infrastructure used by Azure Data Factory, Azure Synapse Analytics and Azure Purview to provide data integration and scanning capabilities across different network environments`. Shouldn't it be cross service detectable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks you could not use the same runtime with DataFactory and Azure Purview.

From the doc - [Known limitations of self-hosted IR sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-shared-self-hosted-integration-runtime-powershell#known-limitations-of-self-hosted-ir-sharing):

> - The sharing feature works only for data factories within the same Azure AD tenant.

From the **Note** in this [Azure Purview doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/manage-integration-runtimes):

> The Purview Integration Runtime cannot be shared with an Azure Synapse Analytics or **Azure Data Factory** Integration Runtime on the same machine. It needs to be installed on a separated machine.

Comment: Thanks. I have two processes, reading different servers. Effectively I have to terminate one if I have to read through the same machine

Comment: @wwnde Yes, it should be like that.